# allocated prepared query error syntax error

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I try to execute a variable query within a custom mysql function, here's the script :

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE FUNCTION is_present(in_id BIGINT, in_table_name VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
  DECLARE stm VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE result BIT DEFAULT 0;

  SET stm := CONCAT('SELECT IF(COUNT(*), 1, 0) INTO result FROM', in_table_name, 'WHERE id=? LIMIT 1');
  PREPARE query FROM stm;
  EXECUTE query USING in_id;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

  RETURN result;
END $

DELIMITER ;
```

Mysql warns me about the syntax :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'stm;   EXECUTE query USING in_id;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
>     RETURN result; ' at line 9

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a semicolon before var name:

```
PREPARE query FROM :stm;
```